# formal definition of "flowcharts"

Tags: reference-request, automata-theory, terminology, formal-methods

I am looking for a formal definition of so-called "flowcharts" used as representation of programs or business processes.

Is there some good one around ?

Thx
JCLL

Comment: I suspect the answer might be no, there are many different types of flowcharts and almost all of them are ad-hoc and the rest are "informal" in that they don't really have any well-defined properties that we could study in a formal way (esp. for business processes). I have a feeling that the moderators will say this isn't a CS theory question...

Comment: I think this might be off topic. Maybe if you phrased the question more carefully it could be on topic? I don't know much about flowcharts, but as far as I understand [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) is pretty well formalized. You might want to start by taking a look there.

Comment: JCLL, please read the FAQ if you have not. This doesn't seem to be a research-level question. (IIRC, there is a definition in the first chapter of Odifreddi's Classical Recursion Theory, vol I.)

Comment: To Kaveh : in an advanced compilation technique, my team is juggling between automata and flowcharts ; this is why I took the liberty of asking this question.

Comment: Perhaps you should reframe the question in terms of your research. I don't think you'll find anything more enlightening than the wikipedia definition of flowcharts (Of course you get data flow diagrams and control flow diagrams, but this too is easily found on wikipedia).

Comment: I agree with Rehno. I would also suggest adding the `application-of-theory` tag.

Comment: I'm pretty sure semantics of flowcharts exist already, probably since the 70s (google "semantics flowcharts"). The semantics of business process notions such as BPMN have recently been defined (google "semantics bpmn"). Perhaps if you are after something between automata and flowcharts, you might want to look at Petri Nets.

Comment: ISO standard for flowcharts: http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=11955

Comment: Standards exists for everything (e.g. CODASYL). I wouldn't touch UML-anything with long pole.

Comment: Let me try. Flowchart is directed labelled graph where each node does some processing and tells you what to do next. :)

Answer (score -1):

If the need is business processes, have a look at this : [link](https://www.conceptdraw.com/How-To-Guide/business-process-flowchart-symbols) and [link](https://www.omg.org/bpmn/Documents/BPMN_Sections_1_and_2.pdf)
else you can go with the normal one [here](https://www.shoulderdoc.co.uk/documents/research_flowchart.pdf).

Comment: Probably useful to flesh out the description of the links, as they are often subject to pretty severe bitrot.